# How to set value of file field with entity_metadata_wrapper

Tags: 7, files, entities

How do you set the value of a file field when using the entity_metadata_wrapper?

I've tried doing this in code:

```
$file = new stdClass();
$file->uid = 1;
$file->uri = $file_path;
$file->filename = basename($file_path);
$file->filemime = file_get_mimetype($file_path);
$file->filesize = filesize($file_path);
$file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
$file->display = '1';
file_save($file); // I also tried: $file = file_save($file);

$node = array(
  'type' => 'news_item',
  'uid' => 1,
  'status' => 1,
  'comment' => 0,
  'promote' => 0,
  'language' => 'en',
);

$entity = entity_create('node', $node);

$ewrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $entity);

$ewrapper->field_document->set((array) $file); // I also tried: $ewrapper->field_document->set($file);

$ewrapper->save(true);
entity_save('node', $entity);
```

But I get this exception:

```
EntityMetadataWrapperException: Invalid data value given. Be sure it matches the required data type and format. in EntityMetadataWrapper->set() (line 122 of C:\wamp\www\drupal\sites\all\modules\entity\includes\entity.wrapper.inc).
```

Any help is very mych appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Wrapping the file array in another array seems to do the trick for me:

```
$file = (array) $file;
$items = array($file);
$ewrapper->field_document->set($items);
```

But I haven't found out *why* yet...

Comment: That does indeed do the trick. Thanks alot for your help, appreciate it!

Comment: I believe it has something to do with the delta index of the field. If you don't assign a delta index to your field (i.e. $ewrapper->field_name->set(); ), you have to wrap another array around it. If you do assign a delta index to your field (i.e. $ewrapper->field_name[0]->set(); ), you can just use $file = (array) $file.

Comment: Yes that makes a lot of sense, thanks for following up

Answer (score 20):

Well I just found out a **simpler and less ugly looking way to set image**.

```
$image_file = A FILE OBJECT; //Lot of choices here : new stdClass(), file_load, etc
$wrapper->FIELD_NAME->file->set($image_file);
```

Just as taxonomy or node/entity reference, the file field name point on a loaded object, thats how I find out.

---

:: EDIT a posteriori ::

Here how I would have do it with OP question.

```
// Get the file
$file = file_save_data(file_get_contents('/my_local_path/img1.jpg'), 'public://remote_name.jpg');

// Wrap' it like one of your French girls
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);

// And set the photo
$wrapper->field_photo->file->set($file);

// And save the node
$wrapper->save();
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function set() on null... I'm able to add some text fields, but adding a file just doesn't work

Comment: @PatrickS You sure you created a file object ? Even the method from Clive didn't work ?

Comment: I'm attempting to migrate some Joomla content into Drupal. The first time I migrate the files, it works. If I erase all the Products and attempt another migration, it doesn't work anymore. The only way I get it to work is from a fresh install. I have stored the Joomla data in a JSON file, which I use to create the entities. At the time I left the comment, I hadn't yet realised that only the first import was working & I was trying all sort of methods to create the entities. I had no idea what was going on since I was able to create all  the fields, except the images!

Comment: The `new stdClass()` comment mislead me a little, assuming I could assign a newly created file object to a field directly. When using this, make sure the file has a fid assigned (i.e. it has been saved at least once), otherwise this will not work.

Comment: How would you apply this for multiple file field ? I think it should be something like `$wrapper->field_photo[]->file->set($file)` but I'm not sure. Have you ever faced this situation?

Answer (score 5):

My node already existed and I had to set the following parameters:

```
$wrapper->field_pdf->set(array('fid'=>$fid, 'display'=>1, 'description'=>'This is a PDF'));
```

Different set-ups may require different parameters I suppose. If you look in your error logs (admin/reports/dblog) you can see what parameters are needed.

Comment: This worked for me. I could add the file field no problem, but it wouldn't show as `display` was `0` for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anybody would find this helpful:

If you don't have an actual file handle and only know the `fid` you can use:

```
$wrapper->field_file->set( array( 'fid'=>1234 ) );
```

And (assuming a file with that fid exists) Drupal will attach the correct file upon `$wrapper->save()`.

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to do it:

```
// By loading the file object in any way
$file_obj = file_load($fid);
$w_containing_node->field_attachment_content->file->set( $file_obj );


// By passing an array with the fid
$w_containing_node->field_attachment_content->set( array('fid' => $fid) );
```

Here is the source of the information: https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/entity-api/entity-metadata-wrappers#example-value-set-save