# Add image files to a Node entity

Tags: entities, media

I have an object which is created by transferring the image from another server. The image obj looks like this:

```
$ImgObj = stdClass Object ( [fid] => 595 
[uri] => public://assets/TLK/TLK-4300.jpg 
[filename] => TLK-4300.jpg 
[filemime] => image/jpeg 
[uid] => 1 
[status] => 1 
[timestamp] => 1459790167 
[filesize] => 24616 
[type] => image 
[metadata] => Array ( [width] => 220 [height] => 140 ) 
)
```

I am creating a node which has other fields in it and I'm trying to add this image object to it. I'm creating a wrapper for the node using:

```
$entity = entity_create('node', $values); //Values is an array defined earlier     
$ewrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $entity);
```

and want to add the image something like this:

`$ewrapper->field_main_image->set($ImgObj);`

I've tried a number of options and can't get it to work. I've googled it and tried various methods but always get an error message saying I'm using the wrong type or something like that. Any help much appreciated - thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set value of file field with entity\_metadata\_wrapper](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/69526/how-to-set-value-of-file-field-with-entity-metadata-wrapper)

Comment: Looks like this is a duplicate of http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/69526/how-to-set-value-of-file-field-with-entity-metadata-wrapper.

Comment: Yes, I have seen both of those links already but I thought maybe there was something different for images as it's not working for me for some reason. Hmm not sure why not though. Thanks anyway at least I know I'm going down the right lines.