# Programmatically populate file field using Entity API

Tags: nodes, entities, files

I need to programmatically generate nodes using some data that I extract from different import files.
For the node creation I use Entity API.
I've written a simple function to which I pass the node data in a structured array and the function imports each field depending on how it's defined:

```
  function my_module_create_function($item, $node_type, $language) {
    $node = entity_create('node', array ('type' => $node_type));
    $entity = entity_metadata_wrapper('node',  $node);
    $entity->language = 'es';//LANGUAGE_NONE; // Or e.g. 'en' if locale is enabled
    //strings
    foreach ($item as $key=> $field) {
      switch ($field['field_type']) {
        case 'multiple-reference':
          if(is_array($field['value'])){
            $entity->$key = $field['value'];
          }else{
            //some alert log
          }
          break;
        case 'file':
          if (file_exists($field['value']) && isset($field['filename']))
          {
            $file = file_get_contents($field['value']);
            $filename = $field['filename'];               
            if(isset($field['folder']) && file_exists($field['folder'])){
              $folder = $field['folder'];
            }else{
              $folder = "public://";
            }
            $file = file_save_data($file, $folder.$filename, FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
            $entity->$key= (array)$file;
          }
          else
          {
            // some alert log
          }
          break;
        case 'long-text':
          $entity->$key->set(array(
            'value' =>  $field['value'],
            //'summary' => '',
            'format' => 'full_html',
          ));
          break;
        case 'geolocation':
          $entity->$key->set(array(
            'latitude' => $field['value']['latitude'],
            'longitude' => $field['value']['longitude'],
            //other elements added here (province, postal_code, country [es, en,...],additional, ...)
          ));
          break;
        default:
          $entity->$key= $field['value'];
        break;
      }
    }
    $entity->status = 1; //(1 or 0): published or not
    $entity->promote = 0; //(1 or 0): promoted to front page
    $entity->comment = 0; // 0 = comments disabled, 1 = read only, 2 = read/write
    // Save the entity
    return $entity->save();
  }
```

This function works great except for the file field type. When I try to import a node with a file it gives me this error:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048
>   Column 'my_field_display' cannot be null

the thing is that I have used the same structure:

```
        $file = file_get_contents("file_path");
        $file = file_save_data($file, $folder.$filename, FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
        $entity->$key= (array)$file;
```

for image fields (or multiple image fields using "`[] =`" instead of " `=` ") it works without any problem. Anyone knows if I'm doing anything wrong with this file field?

Any advice would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer to this question [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/69526/how-to-set-value-of-file-field-with-entity-metadata-wrapper).

Instead of:

```
        $file = file_save_data($file, $folder.$filename, FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
        $entity->$key= (array)$file;
```

It should be:

```
        $file = file_save_data($file, $folder.$filename, FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
        if($file !== false)
        {              
          $entity->$key->file->set($file);
        }
```

This '`if($file !== false)`' is optional just to be sure that we're passing a file object.

> *Note that the difference is that we're not passing the file object as an array and also we're passing it to a 'file' atribute instead of
>   passing it directly to the field.