# How to change a file field value with entity_metadata_wrapper

Tags: 7, nodes

I need to remove a file field value, and instead, assign a new value to it. The file field contains video and the new video is in the videos directory.
This is my code to delete a file field value (which works well)

```
    $node = node_load(37);
    // Get the language for the file field.
    $lang = field_language('node', $node, 'field_video');
    // load the file
    $file = file_load($node->field_video[$lang][0]['fid']);
    // unset the field for the node
    unset($node->field_video[$lang][0]);
    // delete file from disk and from database
    file_delete($file);
    // Save the node.
    node_save($node);
```

But this code which assigns a new value, reports an error. I get this code from [How to set value of file field with entity_metadata_wrapper](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/69526/how-to-set-value-of-file-field-with-entity-metadata-wrapper)

```
    $node = node_load(37);
    $realpath="";
    if ($wrapper = file_stream_wrapper_get_instance_by_uri('public://')) {
      $realpath = $wrapper->realpath();
    }
    $file_path = $realpath."\\video_file\\sarmaye.mp4";
    $file = new stdClass;
    $file->uid = $node->uid;
    $file->filename = pathinfo($file_path, PATHINFO_BASENAME);
    $file->uri = $file_path;
    $file->filemime = file_get_mimetype($file_path);
    $file->display = '1';
    // Make it permanent, otherwise it will get deleted later.
    $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;

    file_save($file);
    $file = (array) $file;
    $items = array($file);
    $ewrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
    $ewrapper->field_video->set($items);
    $ewrapper->save(true);
```

But it reports this error

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'D:\xampp\htdocs\MySiteName\sites\default\files\video_file\sarmaye' for key 'uri': INSERT INTO {file_managed} (uid, filename, uri, filemime, filesize, status, timestamp) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5, :db_insert_placeholder_6); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 1 [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => sarmaye.mp4 [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => D:\xampp\htdocs\MySiteName\sites\default\files\video_file\sarmaye.mp4 [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => video/mp4 [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 4877369 [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => 1 [:db_insert_placeholder_6] => 1468934410 ) in drupal_write_record() (line 7361 of D:\xampp\htdocs\MySiteName\includes\common.inc).

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the uploaded file object rather then the initial file object. Please check the return value of [file_save()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_save/7.x) function.

The error explained that there is duplicate key uri, which means the code is trying to save the initial file object again.

`$ewrapper->field_video->set()` only accept `(array) $file` but not `$items`.

```php
$file = file_save($file);
$file = (array) $file;
$ewrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
$ewrapper->field_video->set($file);
$ewrapper->save(true);
```

Comment: I changed the line `$file = file_save($file);`. The same error reported.

Comment: Let me try to run this snippet...

Comment: I guess you got error message: `EntityMetadataWrapperException: Invalid data value given. Be sure it matches the required data type and format. in EntityMetadataWrapper->set() (line 122 of /var/www/Sites/drupal7.dev/sites/all/modules/contrib/entity/includes/entity.wrapper.inc).`. It caused by feeding wrong parameter to `set()`. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Yep, I got that error. Wait please ...

Comment: I found mistake in code. Please use the most updated one.

Comment: When I use a file that its name has never been used before (I mean the name `sarmaye.mp4` in the code), I get this error **Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in D:\xampp\htdocs\MySiteName\sites\all\modules\entity\modules\callbacks.inc on line 638** but when I use a file which its name has been used before but it is not in the videos directory I again get the error that described in the question. I added the line `$file =(array) $file;` and it worked

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42715/discussion-between-jimmy-ko-and-drupalist).